# i am new to laravel 5.5, learning uploading image and displaying image. uploading image is done. but fetching has some issue

Tags: php, image, validation, laravel-5.5

```
public function show()
    {
        //
        //$list = Train_details::all();
        $list = Train_details::join('master_train_types','train_details.type_id','=','master_train_types.id')
            ->select(
                'train_details.id',
                'train_details.name',
                'train_details.noo',
                'train_details.description',
                'train_details.image',
                'train_details.days',
                'train_details.departure_time',
                'master_train_types.name as type_name'
            )->get();

        if((!file_exists (URL::to('/uploads/'. $list->image))))
            {
                $list->image = 'noimage';
                }

      // echo $list;
       return view('masterAdminPages.showTrains')->with('list',$list);
    }
```

i put my images at PUBLIC folder not in storage/app/public.   but how can i check a image is exists or not if so i want to return a noimage pic. which i have stored in public/uploads folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function index()
  {
    $fetches      = Event::all();
    return view('home',['fetches'=>$fetches]);
  }
```

in my view I'm retrieving this as below

```
<table style="border:1px solid black; width:100%">
          @foreach ($fetches as $num)
          <tr>
            <td><img width="30%" class="img-circle" src="{{ URL::asset('storage/images'.$num->images) }}"></td>
          </tr>
          @endforeach
        </table>
```

Comment: i have done this, but my question is what if i dont have that image. in that case i want to display "noimage" image by default

Comment: if you get null from the database than you can show null image by src="{{ URL::asset('storage/images/no-image.png') }}

Comment: if my databse has a entry but that image does not exists any more, then how to check in controller that my image folder has not any image of that name?

Comment: @if(file_exists( public_path().'/storage/images/imagename' )) or you can try this one $exists = Storage::disk('s3')->exists('file.jpg');

Comment: it's not working.may be i cant not cope with your last comment(code).

Answer (score 0):

```
$list = Train_details::join('master_train_types','train_details.type_id','=','master_train_types.id')
             ->select(
                 'train_details.id',
                 'train_details.name',
                 'train_details.no as noo',
                 'train_details.description',
                 'train_details.image',
                 'train_details.days',
                 'train_details.departure_time',
                 'master_train_types.name as type_name'
             )->get();

            foreach($list as $key=>$value){
                if($value->image==null){
                    $list[$key]->image='noimage';
                }
           }
        // echo $list;
   return view('masterAdminPages.showTrains')->with('list',$list);
     }
```

This is what i want. may be it is not the proper way but it is working if there is no entry for image. it will  show a "noimage"(image name).